# How to round an image used as bullet with amCharts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts, amcharts4

I have at least two image bullets in my amCharts project and I want to round images of one of them named *"bullet"*. Here is the line where a *"bullet"* exists...

```
var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
```

I have found a tutorial on rounding custom images [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/rounding-custom-images-used-bullets/). They are used as bullets in amCharts but it rounds every bullet image and I want it to only round *"bullet"* ignoring *"bullet2"*

Here is my code (full size necessary):

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
var myVar = {
  Red: "#f72c69",
  Normal: "#6887cc",
};

var userA_points = 22;
var userB_points = 20;
var userC_points = 6;
var members_points = 12;
var max_points = Math.max(userA_points, userB_points, userC_points, members_points);
var maxPlus = (max_points + 10);
maxPlus = Math.min(200, Math.max(0, maxPlus));
//console.log(maxPlus);

if (userA_points < members_points) {
  var colorCompare = myVar.Red
} else {
  var colorCompare = myVar.Normal
}

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "name": "Damon",
  "points": userA_points,
  "color": "#5479f2",
  "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Koen-VanGeert-circle-ScripturaEngage.png",
  "bullet2": "Diamonds.png",
  "gameOvers": 3
}, {
  "name": "filip",
  "points": userB_points,
  "color": "#5479f2",
  "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Pauline-Suy-circle-ScripturaEngage.png",
  "bullet2": "Diamonds.png",
  "gameOvers": 2
}, {
  "name": "Patrick",
  "points": userC_points,
  "color": "#5479f2",
  "bullet": "https://www.scripturaengage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Profile-Picture-Pauline-Suy-circle-ScripturaEngage.png",
  "bullet2": "Diamonds.png",
  "gameOvers": 2
}, {
  "name": "All Members",
  "points": members_points,
  "color": colorCompare,
  "bullet": "Members.png",
  "bullet2": "Diamonds.png",
  "gameOvers": 2
}];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "name";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
categoryAxis.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 20;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeDasharray = "4,4";
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = false;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 15;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontWeight = "800";

valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = maxPlus;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 25;

// Do not crop bullets
chart.maskBullets = false;

// Remove padding
chart.paddingBottom = 0;
chart.paddingTop = 50;
// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "points";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "name";
series.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color";
series.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "color";
series.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 25;
series.columns.template.column.cornerRadiusTopRight = 25;
series.columns.template.tooltipHTML = "<img src='your-image.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:21px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>POINTS {valueY.value}</b></span><br><img src='your-image.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:21px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>Game overs: {gameOvers}</b></span><br><img src='your-image.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:21px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>Game overs: {gameOvers}</b></span><br><img src='your-image.png' style='vertical-align:bottom; margin-right: 10px; width:21px; height:21px;'><span style='font-size:14px; color:#000000;'><b>Game overs: {gameOvers}</b></span>";


// Add bullets
var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.width = 120;
image.height = 120;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.dy = 70;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bullet";
image.tooltipHTML = series.columns.template.tooltipHTML;
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());

// Add bullets
var bullet2 = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
var image = bullet2.createChild(am4core.Image);
image.width = 60;
image.height = 60;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "bottom";
image.dy = 60;
image.dx = 50;
image.y = am4core.percent(100);
image.propertyFields.href = "bullet2";
image.tooltipHTML = series.columns.template.tooltipHTML;
image.propertyFields.fill = "color";
image.filters.push(new am4core.DropShadowFilter());
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 700px;
}

body {
  margin: 130 100 100 20;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-weight: 800;
  src: url(helveticaneue-ultrathin.woff);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: You are using amcharts4, the plugin you linked is for amcharts3

Comment: I haven't noticed that... So what do you recommend...

Comment: @SamuelP. I'm no expert on amCharts but I don't see why the Tutorial (it's not a plugin) she linked wouldn't apply to Version 4

Comment: If it's not too much urgent, hold on for a week or so. There's a task in amCharts 4 dev pipeline to implement a property `maskPath` which can be used to set any masking shape to any object, including bullets. That will make so much easier than any other alternatives. Related github post: https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1082

Comment: Thank you @martynasma. I'll definitely wait for it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the first bullet template isn't rounding or masking anything. The images you're using are transparent PNGs. If you set a background (e.g. the color black) on the bullets, you'll see that color appear underneath the image.

```js
bullet.height = 120;
bullet.width = 120;
bullet.background.fill = am4core.color("black");
bullet.contentValign = "top";
bullet.verticalCenter = "top";
bullet.horizontalCenter = "middle";
bullet.contentAlign = "center"
```

As for the second set of bullets (`bullet2`), none of the images in the data are things we can test/see, so there's no way to know what's going on there.

Here's a quick demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/ab60df9b6b084559ec6ae2ceaa604bf1

Now, if you want to add your own clipping mask around the image, thanks to [xorspark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6106614/xorspark) I've figured out how to do that. Create a `Circle` as a child of the first set of bullets, then on the `Image` add an adapter for its `mask` property, in there you'll return the bullet's circle. You'll have to play with alignment-related properties to get the positioning just right.

E.g.

```js
var mask = new am4core.Circle();
mask.radius = 40;
mask.horizontalCenter = "middle";
mask.verticalCenter = "middle";
mask.align = "center";
mask.valign = "top";
mask.parent = bullet;

image.adapter.add("mask", function(mask, target) {
  return target.parent.children.getIndex(1)
});
```

Demo (you'll see less of the image shows than usual):

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/1ee8ad3b525c8ecb3cb0c6e88da441af

Comment: I think a misunderstanding happened here ... I want to round first image bullets ...

Comment: @SaraRee I've updated the answer to include a circular mask around the images. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @SaraRee You're welcome! Thanks for the upvote and accepting it as the answer.